# 404 on api authenticate for node restful

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I am using this tutorial

https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens

to learn about node with restful authentication. I am getting 404s in the route when I post at this

```
http://localhost:8090/api/authenticate
```

Here is the response that I get

```
Cannot POST /api/authenticate
```

and the console shows 404

```
POST /api/authenticate 404 2.465 ms - 30
```

here is my code

```
// =======================
// get the packages we need ============
// =======================
var express     = require('express');
var app         = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');
var morgan      = require('morgan');
var mongoose    = require('mongoose');

var jwt    = require('jsonwebtoken'); // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
var config = require('./config'); // get our config file
var User   = require('./app/models/user'); // get our mongoose model

// =======================
// configuration =========
// =======================
var port = process.env.PORT || 8090; // used to create, sign, and verify tokens
mongoose.connect(config.database); // connect to database
app.set('superSecret', config.secret); // secret variable

// use body parser so we can get info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// use morgan to log requests to the console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// =======================
// routes ================
// =======================
// basic route
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello! The API is at http://localhost:' + port + '/api');
});

app.get('/setup', function(req, res) {
  // create a sample user
  var nick = new User({
    name: 'Nick Cerminara',
    password: 'password',
    admin: true
  });

  // save the sample user
  nick.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('User saved successfully');
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
});


// API ROUTES -------------------

// get an instance of the router for api routes
var apiRoutes = express.Router();

// route to authenticate a user (POST http://localhost:8090/api/authenticate)
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {
console.log(req);
  // find the user
  User.findOne({
    name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {

    if (err) throw err;

    if (!user) {
      res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
    } else if (user) {

      // check if password matches
      if (user.password != req.body.password) {

  res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
      } else {

        // if user is found and password is right
        // create a token
        var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
          expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
        });

        // return the information including token as JSON
        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: 'Enjoy your token!',
          token: token
        });
      }

    }

  });
});


// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

what am  I doing wrong? the / and /setup works just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to actually **use** the `apiRoutes` like this

```
....
....
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens at http://localhost:' + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to route to apiRoutes. Add `app.use('/api', apiRoutes);`

Comment: I tried adding that before app.listen(port); and it still doesnt work